# exec() is not throwing an error, but not running the other executable. Syntax error?

Tags: c, exec, fork, wait

I'm trying to use fork() and exec() to run another program that resides in the same directery. The compiler is not complaining, but the program I am trying to call using execl() is not being run. Any tips? Thank you!

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == -1) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Error\n");
    exit(1);        
}
else if (pid > 0) {
    wait(&status);
}
else {
    execl("./expo.c", "./expo", x, n, (char*) NULL);
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
}
```

I have tried a few different versions of exec() as well and none have worked.

EDIT:
I have changed to    execl("expo","expo",&x,&n,(char*)NULL); , though I am still unsure why this works based on the man pages. The man page says the first argument should be a path, not just the executable. Also, why do I not need ./ for the second argument if I would need that to run that executable in the terminal?

I have got everything working correctly, here is what I changed. Instead of casting the arguments (x and n) into ints then passing them to the child, I passed them as chars and then casted them as ints in the child process.

```
if(pid==-1){
        fprintf (stderr, "Error\n");
    exit(1);        
    }
    else if(pid>0){
        wait(&status);
    }
    else{
        const char *x=argv[1];
        const char *n=argv[2];

        execl("expo","expo",x,n,(char*)NULL);
        perror("execl() failure!\n");       
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     
    }
```

Comment: Can you run the program directly from the shell?

Comment: 2 things, 1) the first argument to execl looks wrong as it looks like you are passing a c file (although you could have a binary with a .c extension) 2) put a perror after execl to see the error message.  No need to check the return value as exec only returns if it fails.

Comment: Why do you say `execl()` is not throwing an error?  With the code presented, how could you tell?  And why would you expect the *compiler* to complain?

Comment: if( execl("./expo.c", "./expo", x, n, (char*) NULL) != -1 ) { printf ("Exec Not throwing an error "); }

Comment: a few observations: 1) the first parameter must be an executable file, not a source file.  2) the parameters 'x' and 'n' must be pointers.  The posted code does not make that obvious.  3) the first and second parameter must be the same. parm 1 looks like a source code file and parm 2 looks like an executable file.

Comment: the function: `_exit()` is a very poor choice as it skips any calls set by `atexit()` and does not 'cleanup'.   Much better to use `exit()`

Comment: @missimer, thank you, changing the argument has helped. Although, even after reading the man pages, I'm confused as to why I would pass the executable argument twice?

Comment: @user3629249: That's true in general, but here, it may be appropriate.  Otherwise your `atexit` functions could be run twice: once in the child and once in the parent.  If there were things that had to be done in the child before the program ended, you should have done them before calling `exec*` because if all goes well it won't return.

Comment: @Mesaboog: The first argument is the path to the file to be executed.  The second argument is the string that the program being executed will receive as `argv[0]` in its `main` function.  The usual convention is for them to be the same, but `execl` lets you decide.

Comment: What are `x` and `n` here?  Can you post a complete example that can be compiled and run?  Calling `execl` with `&x` and `&n` as arguments seems unlikely to be correct.